# Should I publish IP addresses that try to brute force my private web server?

Tags: webserver, brute-force, legal

Ethically and legally, am I allowed to publish IP addresses that tried to brute force my LAMP server? It's a personal website/blog that gets brute forced a lot and I would like to publish them to my website to make an interesting post.

I would just go through the logs and find the IP addresses that tried to attack me. From time to time I report them to https://www.abuseipdb.com/ .

Comment: We cannot tell you what is legal. We don't even know your jurisdiction. The question you need to ask is, "are these IPs tied to innocent parties and will I harm them by shaming them?"

Comment: I remember when I ran a mail server how many hundreds of IPs I had to block just so it wouldn't get overwhelmed.  Some days it would take me an hour just to block the previous night's scans.  I'll never try to run a mail server again.  I'll leave that particular headache to professionals.  Same with my web sites.

Answer (score 9):

Legally?  That depends on the laws of your jurisdiction, and is off-topic for this site.

Ethically?  Consider: most of these attacks aren't being performed by computers owned by the attacker.  They're being performed by home routers, security cameras, refrigerators, and the occasional compromised server.  Most of the IP addresses attacking you are owned by people who wouldn't know what an "IP address" was if it bit them, and would react with total confusion if you told them their FitBit or garage-door opener was attacking other peoples' computers.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have the right to do so, even if not legally. Persons who commit a crime will hardly go to the police . If you do so, you can still use Tor or a proxy. But are you sure that these people do not use Tor or proxies themselves?

Comment: You're assuming these attacks are done one purpose. There's a good chance attacks are done using hosts which are part of a botnet or infected with malware, and the owner isn't even aware that his machine is used for these attacks.

Comment: Using Tor seldom hurts but might give you a false sense of security here. If your server under attack is linkable to you, so will be the information that it was attacked by some IP.

Comment: yes , but it is still better then nothing . It will make tracking a little bit more difficult